# multiprocessing.ThreadPool.imap freezes due to IndexError: pop from an empty deque python

Tags: python, multiprocessing, threadpool

```
pool = ThreadPool(args.threads)
res = pool.imap_unordered(download, urls)
for item in res:
    print(item)
pool.close()
pool.join()
```

I have this issue with imap and imap_unordered. The program itself is downloading images through `requests.get(url)`. Sometimes it finishes without any exception and I don't understand why it happens. I tried to do it with `with ThreadPool(args.threads) as pool:`, but I got the same behaviour. What should I do?

Comment: You might want to search SO for some question on the topic. There seems to be some debate about whether portions of ```requests``` are thread-safe.

Comment: When iterating over the result, it does pop_left on empty deque. I don't know why. Finally, I decided to replace imap with just map for now.